# Issue with visibility layer using iOS (with mapbox-gl)

Tags: safari, mapbox-gl-js

I'm struggling with an issue for several weeks about MapboxGL and layers.

I have a map with layers (raster layer)and I trigger visibility with actions (time, buttons, user gesture, etc)...

With Chrome everything is OK I can set the visibility of layers using the setLayoutProperty method.

My function doesn't work with Safari (on macOS and iOS).
I reproduce the issue using mapbox official example and adding a timer on the layer visibility.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
                map.setLayoutProperty('radar-layer', "visibility", "visible");
            }, 3000);
```

=> https://codepen.io/simon51/pen/eYWjPOz

The normal behavior : the clouds will be displayed after 3 seconds.
(it works with Google Chrome and it reproduces the current issue with Safari)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

OK, it was a bug fixed by a very recent release of mapbox-gl (about raster image and safari)
more here : https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/10698